# Event listener is executed after the event is triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am triggering an event. And its event listener is defined inside the directive's controller. The controller is executed after the event is triggered, hence event listener code is not executed.

```
//HTML code 
<div class="container" ng-controller="ServerController">
    <notification position="top" timeout="5000" class="myClass">   </notification>
</div>
```

**Controller -**

```
if (appUtils.groupCreated === true) {
       console.log("inside"); //getting printed
        $rootScope.$broadcast("notifyEvent", {
            type: "alert-success",
            message: "Server group is successfully created."

        });
       appUtils.groupCreated = false;           
};
```

**Notification directive -**

```
.directive("notification", function($interval) {
return {
restrict: "E",
scope: {
    timeout: "@",
    position: "@"
},
replace: true,
template: '<div><div ng-repeat="notification in notifications" ng-show="displayNotification" class="alert alert-dismissible {{notification.type}} {{notificationPosition}}" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>{{notification.message}}</div></div>',
controller: function($scope) {
    console.log("notification");
    $scope.$on("notifyEvent", function(e, notifyObject) {
       $scope.displayNotification = true;

        // if there are multiple messages
        if (notifyObject.messages && notifyObject.messages.length > 0) {
            $scope.notifications = notifyObject.messages;
        } else {
            $scope.notifications = [{
                message: notifyObject.message,
                type: notifyObject.type
            }];
        }


        if ($scope.position) {
            $scope.notificationPosition = "notify" + $scope.position;
        }

        if ($scope.timeout) {
            $interval(function() {
                $scope.displayNotification = false;
            }, $scope.timeout);
        }
    });
},
link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
    scope.timeout = attributes.timeout;
    scope.position = attributes.position;
}
```

}
   });

The order for console statement is - inside, inside1 and then notification

Comment: Is the controller's snippet executed on the ServerController ng-init event?

Comment: @MichaelZucchetta - No

Comment: The header conflicts with the text.

Comment: All is true, and the question is?

Answer (score 0):

What happens:

- Server controller is first instanciated
- Your directive controller is then instanciated
- Your directive postLink function is executed

Perhaps make your ServerController a directive and $broadcast from a postLink function. By default, directive's link function is a post link function. When the compiler travels through your DOM nodes, from parents to children:

- Controller is instanciated first on the way down
- preLink function is executed on the way down
- postLink function is executed on the way up

[Directive controller and link timing in AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2603-directive-controller-and-link-timing-in-angularjs.htm)